# Laravel PayTM checksum integrate

Tags: checksum, paytm

composer require paytm/paytmchecksum

install after  paytmchecksum.php file which place i insert and how to call paytmchecksum in controller.

insert
app\Paytm\PaytmChecksum.php

namespace App\Paytm;
class PaytmChecksum{

Comment: copy to this file in paytm github

https://github.com/paytm/Paytm_PHP_Checksum/blob/master/paytmchecksum/PaytmChecksum.php

Comment: https://github.com/paytm/Paytm_PHP_Checksum

use this flow

Comment: in controller please use the namespace like use paytm\paytmchecksum\PaytmChecksum; and then you can  call PaytmChecksum::generateSignature(json_encode($paytmParams["body"], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES), "YOUR_MERCHANT_KEY")